# Git post-receive hooks for two repos on the same server

Tags: wordpress, git, githooks

I'm developing a site in Wordpress that I’ve built a template and a plugin for. For my git workflow, I'd like to be able to track the template and the plugin separately with two different repos on the server. Right now I push template commits into a bare repo on the server, which then executes this post-receive hook:

```
#!/bin/sh
export GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/user/public_html/wp-content/themes/custom_theme
export GIT_DIR=/home/user/public_html/custom_theme.git
git checkout -f master
```

And the files show up in the theme folder as intended when I push. But when I tried to set up the exact same thing for the plugin, I get no result. Here is the post-receive hook for the plugin bare repo:

```
#!/bin/sh
export GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/user/public_html/wp-content/plugins/custom_plugin
export GIT_DIR=/home/user/public_html/custom_plugin.git
git checkout -f master
```

When I push to the plugin bare repo, the live plugin directory remains empty and I don't even see any error logs. Does this have to do with using two repos on the same server? I tried adding "unset GIT_DIR" at the start of both hooks to see if that made any difference (it didn't). I've also already checked the file permissions and both hooks are executable for all users. Is there at least a way I can run the plugin hook manually and see what the shell response is?

EDIT:
I added the "echo working 1>&2" to the hook to test if it triggers (per torek's suggestion). After committing a test change and pushing to the server bare repo, here is what I got:

```
stdin: is not a tty
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 376 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Already on 'master'
remote: working
To user@dev.mysite.org:public_html/custom_plugin.git
   f1cc0bb..9a71b5b  master -> master
```

So it seems like the hook is triggering right? I'm getting the "remote: working" line of output above. I'm not exactly sure what all of the output means though. Am I missing something there?

Comment: Make sure your second hook has the right path and is marked executable (if not, git will silently skip it, no warnings or anything).

Comment: Both hooks are rwxr-xr-x. So they should be executable by any user. Should I just 777 it anyway? I've checked and re-checked the path several times and it matches the server.

Comment: Should not need write-able.  Check that the hook is running on push by having it print something inocuous, e.g., "echo working 1>&2"

Comment: Ummmm, well now it's working. I swear I didn't even change anything on the server. Weird. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Huh.  Heisenbugs, what fun :p  :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working just fine now after staring at it for a day.